# How do you avoid a crash if someone tries to access a page without loging in?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Hey so when I try to go to a page that cannot be accessed without logging in, the app crashes. How do I avoid this? The reason why it crashes is because when they try to access that page, the page tries to load data that is undefined.

The error is

TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of null.

This loads up after I try to access a UserProfile page.

I am not sure where to put that a person cannot access any other pages but the home, login, register page basically unless they are logged in already?

app.js file:

```
var express = require('express')
  , app = express()
  , dbUserModel = require('./models/user')
  , db = require('./db')
  , pass = require('./config/passport')
  , passport = require('passport')
  , routes = require('./routes/index')
  , user = require('./routes/user')
  , path = require('path')
  , http = require('http')
  , connect = require('connect')
  , mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , mongoConnect = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test5');

// all environments

app.configure(function(){
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');


    app.use(express.favicon());
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.cookieParser('sabkdasdkjhakhfkahf7232ujdijaw9jok&^&^@88'));
  //app.use(express.cookieSession());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));    
});
  app.get('/', routes.index);
  app.get('/register', user.register);
  app.post('/register', user.registerPost);
  app.get('/login', user.login);
  app.post('/login', user.loginPost);
  app.get('/userProfile', user.userProfile);
  //app.get('/contacts', user.contacts);
  app.get('/editUserProfile', user.editUserProfile);
  app.post('/editUserProfile', user.editUserProfilePost);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
  console.log('Users: ' + db.collections.users);
});
```

Comment: `if(firstName != undefined)` ...

Comment: Actually @AtifMohammedAmeenuddin that would be wrong seeing as its not `firstName` that's `undefined` it would be the parent `object` thing

Comment: Where is your code @Lion789 were not psychic

Comment: @Connor My bad! Anyways I was trolling OP for not giving the complete picture of the problem

Comment: Hey, sorry I included the app.js to make things clearer, basically if I try to go to the userProfile page it crashes the app, since the objects rendered on the page are being pulled out by the cookie info. How do I say right off the bat that if anyone tries to go to any page like that it should not crash the server but just show them an error page?

Comment: Why does it try to load the data at all when the user is not logged in?

Comment: The userProfile page pulls data from the cookie and db query. If there is no cookie though, Ok that actually helped me logically think that I need to add something on the page stating an if statement that if there is no cookies.userid that can be defined then to send an error page? Does that sound correct? Also if that is correct am I suppose to constantly add that on every page after login that acts in a similar way or is there a general way to add it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The straightforward way would be to add a middleware to all routes where a user has to be logged in. In that middleware you decide what to do if the user is not logged in. Depending on the kind of page, you could render a general page or redirect to the login page.

The middleware, let's call it `user.mustBeLoggedIn`, would look something like this:

```
exports.mustBeLoggedIn = function (req, res, next) {
  // Assuming passport always sets req.user when logged in
  if(!req.user) {
    // You could add a redirect query param if you want to be nice and redirect
    // the user back to this page
    res.writeHead(302, { 'Location': '/login' });
    return res.end();
  }

  // If the user is logged in just let the next middleware in the middleware chain handle the request
  next();
};
```

Then where declaring the routes you would ad that middleware before any route that requires the user to be logged in:

```
app.get('/login', user.login);
app.post('/login', user.loginPost);
app.get('/userProfile', user.mustBeLoggedIn, user.userProfile);
```

If you also put all routes that requires being logged in under a directory you could further simplify the code by putting the middleware in a single rule for eg all `/user/*`:

```
app.get('/user/*', user.mustBeLoggedIn);
app.get('/user/profile', user.userProfile);
app.get('/user/editProfile', user.editUserProfile);
app.get('/user/etc', user.etc);
```

This technique can be further enhanced to for example require different user levels, but that's outside the scope of this answer.